# Strange error while using valgrind? a bug maybe?

Tags: c++, linux, profiling, valgrind

I am developing a C++ program and when finished, I wanted to check for memory leaks, but I have found an strange error with valgrind:

```
   ==9106== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
   ==9106==    at 0x4006C58: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
   ==9106==    by 0x42EB637D: free_mem (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
   ==9106==    by 0x42EB5F16: __libc_freeres (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
   ==9106==    by 0x4002451: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:61)
   ==9106==    by 0x42E38EA3: _Exit (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
   ==9106==    by 0x42DC0DF3: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
   ==9106==  Address 0x403f818 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Since it did not tell anything about line number where the invalid delete was present, I had to use the method of commenting blocks out.

The surprise was that I got until the point that I commented all code, and the error still was appearing.

I have finally this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    /* ... all other code */
    return 0;
}
```

What is happening here? a vagrind bug? so, can I safely ignore that error?

I am running valgrind 3.7.0 this way (under Linux):

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./bioweds_client
```

EDIT:

This is the whole code:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: jstuardo
 *
 * Created on March 22, 2013, 7:32 PM
 */


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
/*
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "Settings.h"
#include "FComm.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "Helper.h"

using namespace std;

static string get_optional_parameter(std::map<string, string> parameters, string key) {
    if (parameters.count(key) == 0)
        return "";
    else
        return parameters[key];
}

static bool show_usage(std::string name) {
    std::cerr << "Uso: " << name << " OPCIONES\n\n"
            << "Las opciones posibles son:\n"
            << "\t--command COMANDO\tComando que se les envía a los equipos biométricos\n"
            << "\t--ip IP\t\t\tEspecifica la dirección IP de un equipo\n"
            << "\t--staff STAFF\t\tEspecifica el ID de un funcionario\n"
            << "\t--date_from FECHA\tEspecifica la fecha de inicio de una consulta a la base de datos\n"
            << "\t--date_to FECHA\t\tEspecifica la fecha de término de una consulta a la base de datos\n"
            << "\t--fingers DEDOS\t\tEspecifica los dedos de ambas manos para las cuales realizar una oepración\n"
            << "\t--verbose\t\tMuestra por consola la operación de la aplicación\n"
            << "\t--retries INTENTOS\t\tCantidad de intentos que debe realizar para la conexión en caso de error de comunicación\n"
            << "\t--delay RETARDO\t\tCantidad de milisegundos a esperar luego que se envía el comando\n"
            << "\t--thread\t\tEnvía los comandos a los equipos mediante threads\n"
            << "\t--source SOURCE \t\tEspecifica archivo existente en el equipo indicado por IP\n"
            << "\t--target TARGET \t\tEspecifica archivo a crear en el PC\n\n"
            << "Los comandos posibles son:\n"
            << "\tcheck\tVerifica la comunicación con el equipo dado por el parámetro --ip\n"
            << "\tbroadcast\tTransmite todos los archivos existentes en la carpeta \"" << FComm::SHARE_FOLDER << "\" a todos los equipos configurados, excepto al indicado por el parámeto --ip\n"
            << "\tset_time\tSincroniza la fecha y hora de todos los equipos configurados con la fecha y hora del PC\n"
            << "\tget_fingerprints\tObtiene los archivos de huellas desde el equipo indicado por el parámetro --ip del funcionario indicado por el parámetro --staff\n"
            << "\tdelete_fingerprints\tBorra las huellas de todos los equipos configurados. Las huellas se indican con el parámetro --fingers como sigue:    0:1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9 (para todos o algunos de los dedos\n"
            << "\tget_logs\tObtiene las marcaciones existentes en los equipos configurados (archivos wdjl y los almacena en la carpeta \"" << FComm::WDJL_FOLDER << "\")\n"
            << "\tprocess_logs\tProcesa todos los registros existentes en la carpeta \"" << FComm::WDJL_FOLDER << "\"\n"
            << "\tget_archives\tObtiene el archivo de funcionarios y los almacena en la carpeta \"" << FComm::SHARE_FOLDER << "\")\n"
            << "\tget_photos\tObtiene las fotos de las marcas que aún no tienen foto de todos los equipos configurados. Si se especifican fechas, se traen solo las fotos de las marcas de ese intervalo.\n"
            << "\tget_one_photo\tObtiene una única foto desde el equipo indicado por IP." << endl;

    return true;
}
*/

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "all commented" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    /*
    bool verbose = false;
    bool multithread = false;
    int retries = 0;
    int delay = 0;
    std::string command;
    std::map<string, string> parameters;

    // Lee los parámetros de la línea de comandos
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (string(argv[i]) == "--command") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                command = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--ip") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["ip"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--staff") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["staff"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--date_from") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["date_from"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--date_to") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["date_to"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--fingers") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["fingers"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--retries") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                retries = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--delay") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                delay = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--verbose") {
            verbose = true;
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--thread") {
            multithread = true;
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--source") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["source"] = argv[++i];
        } else if (string(argv[i]) == "--target") {
            if (i + 1 < argc)
                parameters["target"] = argv[++i];
        }
    }

    string executable = argv[0];
    executable = executable.substr(executable.find_last_of("/") + 1);

    bool salida = false;

    if (command == "")
        salida |= show_usage(executable);
    else if (command == "get_fingerprints" && (parameters.count("ip") == 0 || parameters.count("staff") == 0))
        salida |= show_usage(executable);
    else if (command == "delete_fingerprints" && parameters.count("fingers") == 0)
        salida |= show_usage(executable);
    else if (command == "get_bulk_photos" && parameters.count("ip") == 0)
        salida |= show_usage(executable);
    else if (command == "delete_bulk_photos" && parameters.count("ip") == 0)
        salida |= show_usage(executable);
    else if (command == "get_archives" && parameters.count("ip") == 0)
        salida |= show_usage(executable);    
    else if (command == "get_one_photo" && parameters.count("ip") == 0 && parameters.count("source") == 0 && parameters.count("target") == 0)
        salida |= show_usage(executable);

    if (command != "check" && command != "broadcast" && command != "set_time" && command != "get_fingerprints"
            && command != "delete_fingerprints" && command != "get_logs" && command != "process_logs"
            && command != "get_photos" && command != "get_bulk_photos" && command != "delete_bulk_photos" 
            && command != "get_one_photo" && command != "get_archives" && command != "decrypt_file")
        salida |= show_usage(executable);

    if (salida)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    Helper::CheckFolder(FComm::LOG_FOLDER);
    Log log(FComm::LOG_FOLDER + "common.log");

    if (verbose) {
        cout << "Ejecutando comando [" << command << "] con los parámetros:" << endl;
        for (map<string, string>::iterator it = parameters.begin(); it != parameters.end(); it++)
            cout << "\t" << it->first << " = " << it->second << endl;

        cout << "\tReintentos = " << retries << endl;

        cout << "\tRetardo = " << delay << " milisegundos" << endl;

        if (multithread) cout << "\tMultithread" << endl;
        else cout << "\tSecuencial" << endl;
    }

    log.Write("Ejecutando comando [" + command + "] con los parámetros:");
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = parameters.begin(); it != parameters.end(); it++)
        log.Write("\t" + it->first + " = " + it->second);

    if (multithread) log.Write("\tMultithread");
    else log.Write("\tSecuencial");

    Settings settings;
    FComm fcomm(settings, retries, delay, verbose, multithread);

    bool exito = false;
    if (command == "check")
        exito = fcomm.Check(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"));
    else if (command == "broadcast")
        exito = fcomm.Broadcast(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"));
    else if (command == "set_time")
        exito = fcomm.SetTime(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"));
    else if (command == "get_fingerprints")
        exito = fcomm.GetFingerprints(parameters["staff"], parameters["ip"]);
    else if (command == "delete_fingerprints")
        exito = fcomm.DeleteFingerprints(parameters["staff"], get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"), get_optional_parameter(parameters, "fingers"));
    else if (command == "get_logs")
        exito = fcomm.GetLogs(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"));
    else if (command == "process_logs")
        exito = fcomm.ProcessLogs();
    else if (command == "get_archives")
        exito = fcomm.GetArchives(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"));    
    else if (command == "get_photos")
        exito = fcomm.GetPhotos(get_optional_parameter(parameters, "ip"), get_optional_parameter(parameters, "date_from"), get_optional_parameter(parameters, "date_to"));
    else if (command == "get_one_photo")
        exito = fcomm.GetOnePhoto(parameters["ip"], parameters["source"], parameters["target"]);
    else if (command == "decrypt_file")
        exito = fcomm.DecryptFile(parameters["source"]);

    log.Write("Saliendo en forma exitosa.");

    return exito ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
     */
}
```

And this is the whole valgrind output:

```
[root@Linux v2]# valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./bioweds_client
==10441== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10441== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10441== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10441== Command: ./bioweds_client
==10441== 
all commented
==10441== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==10441==    at 0x4006C58: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==10441==    by 0x42EB637D: free_mem (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==10441==    by 0x42EB5F16: __libc_freeres (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==10441==    by 0x4002451: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:61)
==10441==    by 0x42E38EA3: _Exit (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==10441==    by 0x42DC0DF3: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.5.so)
==10441==  Address 0x403f818 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10441== 
==10441== 
==10441== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10441==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10441==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 9 frees, 186 bytes allocated
==10441== 
==10441== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10441== 
==10441== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10441== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 33 from 8)
[root@Linux v2]#
```

Thanks in advance,

Jaime

Comment: I highly doubt it's a bug in valgrind. I tried that exact code on that exact version of valgrind and didn't get an error.  Are you sure everything is really commented out? What is your compile command?

Comment: If you compile with debug symbols, Valgrind should tell you the line numbers.

Comment: I added the whole code and the whole valgrind output. Please check. Also, I am using debug version.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in libc that has been fixed.
You can ignore this bug, or use the valgrind option `--run-libc-freeres=no` to avoid it.

`__libc_freeres` is called at exit to release resources;
the bug is that memory allocated from a separate pool
is being returned to the libc malloc/free area.

For details, see http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.exit_errors
and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=629976

Answer (score 0):

Since _Exit is on the stack trace, the invalid free is probably happening in the destructor for some static or global variable.   It might not be in your source file, but in a class you've #included or even a library you're linking with.

Comment: The only included libraries are standard ones, as you saw in the source code, and the non standard library I am linking with is the PostgreSQL library (which are functions, not classes), but since I commented all code, no call to external function is called. Regards,